# Convert NIST sphere format (SPH) to WAV

Tags: audio, media-converter

I'm looking for a program that can convert audio files from NIST sphere format (SPH) to WAV.

Any license, operating system and price is fine.

---

I tried [SoX (Sound eXchange)](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) (free, CLI, Linux):

```
sudo apt-get install -y sox
sox file.sph file.wav
```

but with some files (e.g., WSJ speech recognition corpus) I did the message:

> sph: unsupported coding `pcm,embedded-shorten-v1.1'

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [sph2pipe_v2.5](http://www.openslr.org/resources/3/sph2pipe_v2.5.tar.gz) ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/sph2pipe_v2.5)):

- Free
- open source
- Linux, Mac OS X , Microsoft Windows

To use it on Microsoft Windows:

```
sph2pipe.exe file.sph file.wav
```

To compile on Linux (from the readme provided with the program):

```
gcc -o sph2pipe *.c -lm
```